# Unity 3D UWP build fails: System.Xml cannot be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I am trying to build my project for UWP, HoloLens to be specific. I am getting XML data from the web and parse that using NewtonSoft.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode (XmlNode node) (returns string). Here's a list of stuff you need to know and stuff that I tried already:

My Unity version is 2018.1.3f1, Scripting Runtime Version is .NET 4,x Equivalent, Scripting Backend is Mono, API Comp. Lvl is .NET 4.x as well.

The exact error message: Assets\Scripts\RestManager.cs(62,23): error CS7069: Reference to type 'XmlNode' claims it is defined in 'System.Xml', but it could not be found

I double checked the necessary includes and also checked for a similar error described here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1986

What I want to do works both in a standalone build and the editor.

Any help is much appreciated!

----- Edit: Update -----

Hey,

I am still trying to get this to work and these errors showed up after my last attempt to add the package to a XAML-based built from Unity:

Install-Package : NU1107: Version conflict detected for System.Collections. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 HoloEPA -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.0.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Collections (>= 4.3.0) 
 HoloEPA -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.0.0 -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime 1.0.0 -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-arm 1.0.0 -> System.Collections (= 4.0.10).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Xml.XmlDocument -Version 4.3.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'HoloEPA'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Xml.XmlDocument -Version 4.3.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 1):

`XmlNode` is not part of .NET Core (which is used by UWP). It works in the editor or standalone builds because they are using a different version of .NET (depending on your version of Unity, it could be using Mono or .NET 2.X or 4.X).

Add [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/) to your Visual Studio project using NuGet, and you will be able to use `XmlNode` again. This assembly will define the `XmlNode` class under the `System.Xml` namespace, as expected.

Comment: Thanks Kwinten . While I have downloaded and added it to the package and also changed the PathHint in the Assembly-CSharp.csproj file, it still give me the same error message. Packages.config, however, clearly states it added it.
Maybe I just have to refrain from using Newtonsoft and write my own parser?

Comment: Normally there shouldn't be any problems if you installed the package correctly. Make sure to use NuGet package manager from within Visual Studio. I would refrain from trying to create your own parser - there are plenty of other viable alternatives if Newtonsoft.Json keeps failing for you.

Comment: And there is no other steps required in Unity, such as the one that I (unsuccessfully) tried?

Comment: I noticed that Unity gives a path to their System.Xml. dll in mono, and changing the path in the .csproj file is useless for it re-creates those files every time i try to  build the VS project. I'm still baffled with this problem

Comment: You wouldn't be "changing the path" to System.Xml. Adding the package I mentioned through NuGet in your VS project should simply define the `XmlNode` class under the System.Xml namespace. If added properly, you should see a reference to the package in your `project.json` file.

Comment: Hey, 

I am still trying to get this to work and these errors showed up after my last attempt to add the package to a XAML-based built from Unity: